# How to compare two columns using Solr?

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4, solrcloud

Compare two columns in `solr` if two fields are equal display `true` or `else` false.

`CASE WHEN o_is_follow = o_follow_id THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE'.`

Comment: where do you it to be compared...while indexing or while searching?

Comment: while searching...

Answer (score 0):

As per as I know comparing one field to another within a document is not supported in either `Solr`.

I think it can be achieved by one option of creating another field while `indexing` only.

You can have another field `(boolean)`. Make this field as `boolean` type and can be used while searching. Create a `o_is_follow_present` field and set it to true for documents matching it while `indexing`.

Use the same field as one of your filter criteria..

Comment: can you check if this works for you https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#Boolean_Functions... this is been added in solr4..... https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Function+Queries

Comment: like..exists(myField) will return true if myField has a value,

Comment: make two fields has a single field in solr schema.xml and search name=something and type = boolean.

Comment: Not yet..Still trying

Answer (score 0):

`{!frange l=1 u=1}strdist(o_is_follow, o_follow_id,edit)`
For 100% similarity between o_is_follow and o_follow_id.

`{!frange l=0 u=0.999}strdist(o_is_follow, o_follow_id,edit)`
For maximum 99.9% of similarity between o_is_follow and o_follow_id.