# How to perform comparison on solr colums

Tags: web, solr, fetch

I have a solr indexed table in which I want to filter the results if one column is greater than the other, so far I am able to specify the range of a particular column but cannot do comparing of two columns. I read in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36996043/how-to-compare-two-columns-using-solr) that I need to create a new column in which I have to store the comparison and then fetch the results from there. But I have no clue on how to begin with it. Any help will be appreciated.

Edit 1:

Show results if column1 > column2

Comment: I think you will get answer from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49388047/4392892

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a function query in a `fq` parameter (`fq` stands for filter query, but accepts a query parsed that allows functions):

```
fq={!frange l=0}sub(column1,column2)
```

(If you don't want to include documents where column1 and column2 are equal, change 0 to `0.1` or something similar)

If you're always comparing these two columns in the same, the previous answer about doing it at index time is really the best way, as it allows Solr to cache the result and built a proper index across the result.

Exactly how you do that depends on how you're indexing, so it'll be up to your own code. You'll define a boolean field `column1_larger_than_column2` (which has the BoolField type), then assign a value based on the result of the subtraction:

```
doc.set('column1_larger_than_column2', (column1 - column2) > 0)
```

Comment: I tried using this . but it shows `can not use FieldCache on multivalued field:`

Comment: Make the field non-multivalued. What would `sub()` on a multivalued field mean?

Answer (score 0):

@MatsLindh Great answer! But I think there is an error in writing. It should be sub, not sum:

```
fq={!frange l=0 incl=false}sub(column1,column2)
```

to find only documents where column1's value is greater than column2's value or

```
{!frange l=0 incl=false}sub(column2,column1)
```

to find only documents where column1's value is lower than column2's value.

Also "incl=false" ensures that column1 is always greater/lower than column2, never equal.

To find >= or <= just omit "incl=false".